# EntityFrameworkCore - Add new Column to Join table

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities:

```
public class Blog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
        Blogs = new List<Blog>();
    }
}
```

Relationship between them is many-to-many. EFCore implicitly creates table BlogPost like:

[image]

I want to add new column to this join table  - Order of type int, but I don't have entity BlogPost in my code. Is there any way to add (and use) that column?

Update #1

I've tried to add entity BlogPost manually

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public long BlogsId  { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public long PostsId { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public List<BlogPost> BlogPost { get; set; }
    public Post()
    {
        Blogs = new List<Blog>();
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public List<BlogPost> BlogPost { get; set; }

    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPost { get; set; }
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {  }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Posts)
            .WithMany(x => x.Blogs);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(x => x.BlogPost).WithOne(x => x.Blog).HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogsId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(x => x.BlogPost).WithOne(x => x.Post).HasForeignKey(x => x.PostsId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().HasKey(x => new { x.BlogsId, x.PostsId });
    }
}
```

But i get an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot use table 'BlogPost' for entity type 'BlogPost' since it is being used for entity type 'BlogPost (Dictionary<string, object>)' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship. Add a foreign key to 'BlogPost' on the primary key properties and pointing to the primary key on another entity typed mapped to 'BlogPost'.'

Comment: Well, why not add a `BlogPost` entity to your code...

Comment: EFCore's going to [make something internally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) to handle it; you might as well just externalize it, create an entity and add the column. DOn't forget to adjust your nav properties so they reference the new middle-man entity

Comment: I treid but i get an error -> see Update #1 :)

Comment: `Blog` should have a `ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts`, Post should have the same. You don't need the `public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }` on Blog (for example) any more. If you now want to know what posts a blog has its `myBlog.BlogPosts.Select(bp => bp.Post)`

Comment: Bring in a local instance of your db and manually create the table in sql. Then scaffold that db and see what EF generates.

Comment: Remember to keep your pluralizations sensible: you've got properties that are called BlogPost (implying singular) but are collections. This will be a source of confusion you should aim to avoid

Comment: (I would also have called the Id column in Blogs as BlogId, rather thn BlogsId, but it's slightly easier to read through even if it's at odds with your entity being called Blog)

Comment: @Caius Jard, Thanks a lot! I will change my naming convention I the way you said in previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard), problem is solved:

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    public Post()
    {
        
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }

    public Blog()
    {
    }
}

public class BlogPost
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public long BlogsId  { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public long PostsId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }  
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPost { get; set; }
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {  }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(x => x.BlogPosts).WithOne(x => x.Blog).HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogsId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(x => x.BlogPosts).WithOne(x => x.Post).HasForeignKey(x => x.PostsId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>().HasKey(x => new { x.BlogsId, x.PostsId });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what problem is solving this answer. All this is the well known and [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#indirect-many-to-many-relationships) old fashioned way of doing many-to-many, supported by EF Core from version one.

Comment: Yea, but now (as far as I know) you can make many-to-many relationships, without specifying join entity (in this case BlogPost), EFCore will take care about that and make join table in database. The old-fashion way for many-to-many relationships is to create two one-to-many relationships with join entity. The problem is when you use "new" approach but you want to add new column to join entity, you don't have one in your code, so you must re-create that entity in old-fashion way and add new property to it.

Comment: That's not exactly true. And also is covered in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration), starting with *"Additional data can be stored in the join entity type, but for this it's best to create a bespoke CLR type.* The provided `Post` / `Tag` example there is basically identical to your `Blog` / `Post`, however they also show how the two approaches can be combined.

Comment: Presumably after changing this, you had to modify all the code that add joins to the records? (e.g. you can't now write "blog.Posts.Add(new Post());")

Comment: Yea, you have to change code to use BlogPost entity :)